# Cannot find cdi-api dependency through wildfly BOM

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, maven-bom

I am building a project that runs on top of Wildfly 14.0.1-Final.

I wanted to try the BOM feature of maven, so I thought: "I will add the wildfly 14 BOM to the dependency management of my parent POM, and then I will only need to define the groupId and artifactId of each artifact, without caring about version number/scope".

So, in my parent POM, I did add:

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
         <artifactId>wildfly</artifactId>
         <version>14.0.1.Final</version>
         <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and to my children POM, I did add a reference to the CDI API:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Yet maven protests that it does not have the version for cdi-api.

The error is:

> ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
> [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing. @ line 29, column 15
> @

I have also tried with the `wildfly-javaee8` BOM artifact.

What am I missing/missunderstanding?

Comment: Do you have a example of the error? Also the dependency should be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Your comment helped me find the problem, thank you. I have added the error message for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

@JamesR.Perkins comment made me realize that I did not have setup the *import* scope for the POM. Also, the correct artifact is org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-javaee8

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
         <artifactId>wildfly-javaee8</artifactId>
         <version>14.0.1.Final</version>
         <scope>import</scope>
         <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

James was right in that I need to define the scope as *provided* when I needed to use the dependency, otherwise it cdi-api.jar would end packaged in the ear and this could cause problems.

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score -1):

When you add a dependency to the  section of your parent POM, it sets a default version for that dependency, but it does not automatically add it to the dependencies section of your children POMs.

In your case, you need to add the  for cdi-api to the  section of your children POMs, not just in the  section of your parent POM.

This should like this:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.1.Final</version> <!-- version should match the version of wildfly BOM you are using -->
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also, you can use wildfly-javaee8 BOM artifact instead of wildfly artifact that you are using, it covers all the dependencies you will need for your wildfly application development.

You can also check your wildfly documentation for more information on how to use BOM feature in wildfly.

Comment: The point of adding the POM is to avoid having to specify the version at the dependencies section. And when I add a dependency directly at dependencyManagement, then at the dependencies section I do not need to specify the version.